# Разница между добавлением элементов через innerHtml и appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom

Добрый день, знатоки javascript.
Есть ли какая-то разница в добавлении элементов через `innerHTML` или `appendChild`?
У меня есть длинные строки, которые надо добавить, например

```
<tr><td><img class='button' alt='delete'></td></tr>
```

Поскольку это single page application, есть вероятность того, что к только что добавленным элементам придётся обращаться (вешать обработчики, удалять и так далее).
При добавлении через `appendChild` это, естественно, занимает много строчек кода и читабельность кода падает.
Если добавить просто с помощью шаблонов-строк, читабельность повысится. Есть ли какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: _Есть ли какая-то разница в добавлении элементов через innerHTML или appendChild?_ - принципиальная!

Answer (score 2):

Разница между указанными функциями - принципиальная. Они делают абсолютно разные вещи.

### [`.innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

> Удаляет **все** дочерние элементы, разбирает полученную строку и результат добавляет как дочерние элементы.

---

### [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

> Метод `Node.appendChild()` добавляет узел в конец списка дочерних узлов.

Comment: Так уж и принципиальная :)

Comment: немного неправильно сформулировал задачу: 1. сначала делаю createElement('tr'). Потом в него набиваю td-шки. Могу набить через createElement, потом appendChild. Могу через innerHTML. В конце новую строку, естественно добавляю в конец существующих строк, т.е. appendChild. Вопрос в том, после создания tr, как лучше набить ее td-шками, с точки зрения производительности, правильности и тд.

Comment: чтобы не быть тупишкой, сразу покажу: есть такая таблица:https://habrastorage.org/web/ed3/309/28b/ed330928b69942a69cbdd89f033316c6.png Собственно мне надо добавить новую строку в неё. Как это лучше сделать: appendChild или innerHTML.

Comment: @Aid, конечно, полный цикл очищения и разбора, вместо одной операции вставки :)

Comment: @ТобакаловКаниет, _лучше_ - это понятие относительное: если у тебя _новый_ элемент и ты его хочешь заполнить - то разницы может и не быть (возможно в производительности, но нужно сильно постараться, чтобы она стала заметна)

Comment: Принципиально разное - это `appendChild` и `:hover`, например, а эти двое не имеют кучу общего (js, методы нод, манипулирование DOM (и даже потомками)).